# Fastlane screengrab saves tablet screenshot in phonescreenshots folder instead of seven or ten inch screenshots folder

Tags: android, fastlane, fastlane-deliver, fastlane-snapshot

I need to take screenshots from a Mobile and a tablet. When I run fastlane screengrab command it saves both devices screenshots in phonescreenshots folder. Please let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: Yeah got the solution. While executing 'fastlane screengrab' command we need to set --device_type to specify the device. We can pass any of string value from the following: phone, sevenInch, tenInch, tv, wear.